# Ubuntu Raring Installation

Tags: ros, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu Raring (13.04) which I don't think is supported by ROS yet. In order to install ROS I had to use the quantal version which downloaded both raring and quantal files. Does anyone know if mixing these files will cause problems? Also, when will the next release of ROS be, and will it support Ubuntu 13?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65614/ubuntu-raring-installation/) by [ishiguro](https://answers.ros.org/users/5199/ishiguro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-06-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-06-22**:
Debian packages of ROS Hydro are already available for Ubuntu Raring 13.04. The official release is expected for the end of July.

ROS Groovy will not be forward ported to Raring. So either use the currently available package of Hydro or build Groovy from source (which is pretty straight forward).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are referring to .deb files: Yes, this might cause problems and I wouldn't recommend it. If you can contain that to ros-only package maybe, you can get away with it.

You can try a source install instead.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0